# Perl Regular Expression to insert/substitute in a string at specific places

Tags: regex, string, perl, substitution, string-substitution

Given a url the following regular expression is able insert/substitute in words at certain points in the urls.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
#use diagnostics;

my @insert_words = qw/HELLO GOODBYE/;
my $word = 0;
my $match;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    foreach my $word (@insert_words)
    {
        my $repeat = 1;
        while ((my $match=$_) =~ s|(?<![/])(?:[/](?![/])[^/]*){$repeat}[^/]*\K|$word|)
        {
            print "$match\n";
            $repeat++;
        }

    print "\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/rabbit/
http://www.superuser.co.uk/dog/cat/rabbit/hamster/
10.15.16.17/dog/cat/rabbit/
```

**The output given (for the first example url in `__DATA__` with the `HELLO` word):**

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dogHELLO/cat/rabbit/
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/catHELLO/rabbit/
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/rabbitHELLO/
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/rabbit/HELLO
```

**Where I am now stuck:**

I would now like to alter the regular expression so that the output will look like what is shown below:

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dogHELLO/cat/rabbit/
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/catHELLO/rabbit/
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/rabbitHELLO/
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/rabbit/HELLO
#above is what it already does at the moment
#below is what i also want it to be able to do as well
http://www.stackoverflow.com/HELLOdog/cat/rabbit/  #<-puts the word at the start of the string
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/HELLOcat/rabbit/
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/HELLOrabbit/
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/rabbit/HELLO
http://www.stackoverflow.com/HELLO/cat/rabbit/  #<- now also replaces the string with the word
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/HELLO/rabbit/
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/HELLO/
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/rabbit/HELLO
```

But I am having trouble getting it to automatically do this within the one regular expression.

Any help with this matter would be highly appreciated, many thanks

Comment: Did you mean to put `/dog/cat/rabbit/HELLO` twice?

Comment: @ikegami - good question, I would like it not to make duplicates, i left it in the question so others could understand the kind of output i wanted to achieve more easily, thanks

Comment: **This might not be a job for regexes, but for existing tools in your language of choice.**  What language are you using? You probably don't want to use a regex, but rather an existing module that has already been written, tested, and debugged.

If you're using PHP, you want the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.


If you're using Perl, you want the [`URI`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/) module.



If you're using Ruby, use the [`URI`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) module.

Comment: I'm using perl, thanks for the advice, I don't know how I've got by without using the URI module yet, thanks

Comment: @AndyLester - I assume that I will need to use perl `URI::Escape` and `uri_unescape($url)` to view the urls in my arrayref data structure in the more 'human readable' form when they are printed to STDOUT, as a number of characters in my urls are percent encoded. However it would always be best to use `uri_escape($url)` to percent encode the characters when actually GETing the particular url using `LWP::UserAgent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use URI qw( );

my @insert_words = qw( HELLO );

while (<DATA>) {
   chomp;
   my $url = URI->new($_);
   my $path = $url->path();

   for (@insert_words) {
      # Use package vars to communicate with /(?{})/ blocks.
      local our $insert_word = $_;
      local our @paths;
      $path =~ m{
         ^(.*/)([^/]*)((?:/.*)?)\z
         (?{
            push @paths, "$1$insert_word$2$3";
            if (length($2)) {
               push @paths, "$1$insert_word$3";
               push @paths, "$1$2$insert_word$3";
            }
         })
         (?!)
      }x;

      for (@paths) {
         $url->path($_);
         print "$url\n";
      }
   }
}

__DATA__
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/rabbit/
http://www.superuser.co.uk/dog/cat/rabbit/hamster/
http://10.15.16.17/dog/cat/rabbit/
```

Answer (score 1):

Without crazy regexes:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use URI qw( );

my @insert_words = qw( HELLO );

while (<DATA>) {
   chomp;
   my $url = URI->new($_);
   my $path = $url->path();

   for my $insert_word (@insert_words) {
      my @parts = $path =~ m{/([^/]*)}g;
      my @paths;
      for my $part_idx (0..$#parts) {
         my $orig_part = $parts[$part_idx];
         local $parts[$part_idx];
         {
            $parts[$part_idx] = $insert_word . $orig_part;
            push @paths, join '', map "/$_", @parts;
         }
         if (length($orig_part)) {
            {
               $parts[$part_idx] = $insert_word;
               push @paths, join '', map "/$_", @parts;
            }
            {
               $parts[$part_idx] = $orig_part . $insert_word;
               push @paths, join '', map "/$_", @parts;
            }
         }
      }

      for (@paths) {
         $url->path($_);
         print "$url\n";
      }
   }
}

__DATA__
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/rabbit/
http://www.superuser.co.uk/dog/cat/rabbit/hamster/
http://10.15.16.17/dog/cat/rabbit/
```

Comment: excellent idea getting rid of the regexes for this solution, thanks, it will make my life a lot easier in the rest of my program as well.

Comment: Don't know which is faster, if that's critical.

Comment: I know I need to change the regex to `my @parts = $path =~ m{[/=&]([^/=&]*)}g;` to get it to separate it by the other characters I specify (/=&), and not just the slashes. But I don't know what to change next as `map "/$_", @parts;` will obviously always output it with a slash even if it was an `=` or a `&` that was found in the url? thanks  a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

one more solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @insert_words = qw/HELLO GOODBYE/;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    /(?<![\/])(?:[\/](?![\/])[^\/]*)/p;
    my $begin_part = ${^PREMATCH};
    my $tail = ${^MATCH} . ${^POSTMATCH};
    my @tail_chunks = split /\//, $tail; 

    foreach my $word (@insert_words) {                      
        for my $index (1..$#tail_chunks) {
            my @new_tail = @tail_chunks;

            $new_tail[$index] = $word . $tail_chunks[$index];
            my $str = $begin_part . join "/", @new_tail;
            print $str, "\n";

            $new_tail[$index] = $tail_chunks[$index] . $word;
            $str = $begin_part . join "/", @new_tail;  
            print $str, "\n";
        }

        print "\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
http://www.stackoverflow.com/dog/cat/rabbit/
http://www.superuser.co.uk/dog/cat/rabbit/hamster/
10.15.16.17/dog/cat/rabbit/
```